# Changing Mail "Get All New Mail" shortcut adds shift key

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, apple-mail

I'm attempting to change the keyboard shortcut for Apple Mail's "Get All New Mail" command to <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> instead of the default <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>N</kbd>. When I add a new App Shortcut for that combo in System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts, Mail's menu shows <kbd>Command</kbd>-*<kbd>Shift</kbd>*-<kbd>R</kbd> instead.

**Before:**

[image: Mail before adding shortcut]

**Adding shortcut:**

[image: Adding shortcut]

**After:**

[image: Mail after adding shortcut]

I realize I'm stealing the keyboard shortcut for Reply, but that's fine (and it disappears from Reply as one would expect). But why is Mail adding the shift key when I explicitly didn't specify it in System Preferences?